# Statistics: Expected return of investment

Tags: statistics

I want to solve the following exercise:

We have a budget of 10 000 [some currency]. We divide it into two parts, w and 1-w.
The part w has an expected return of 8% with a standard deviation of 25%, and part 1-w has a guaranteed return of 2%.

**How can the return be expressed as a function of w?**

I assume that one part will be 0.02*(1-w) - but how would I include the standard deviation into this function?

Answer (score 1):

Since one of the parts has standard deviation $0$ the return is not much complicated.

We have an expected return of $\mu = 0.08w+0.02(1-w)=0.02+0.06w$

And the standard deviation will simply be $\sigma = 0.25w$. That's because $\sigma_{XY}=\sqrt{\sigma_X^2+\sigma_Y^2}$

Comment: oh I see...that simple indeed! I had no idea..